# how can I in SQL get a list of all occurrences in a certain filed using regex

Tags: regex, oracle

Imagine you have a field with a lot of texts and you want to get a list of substrings that match a certain pattern (it's important to know which ones not just how many).

I'm a bit surprised I cannot do this using [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) but I think there must be a way of doing this, just can't easily figure out how.

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_me (
    text varchar(3000)
);

insert into test_me values (
'obj_a, obj_b,
trx_a, trx_c,
obj_c,
obj_d,
obj');
```

For this you would like to retrieve:

```
obj_a, obj_b, obj_c, obj_d, obj
```

I was playing with something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '(obj(.*))', 1, 3) "REGEXP_SUBSTR"FROM test_me;
```

Which can give me either the first, the second, whatever occurrence but not all

If we are using normal regex in other languages I can get all the matching groups and just loop over the matching groups but I could not find a way to do this in oracle. I guess I could "unpivot" this field into a new table per line and then process each line, which is not exactly what I want because even in the same line you can have several occurrences that are important, is there not an easy way to do this?

The use case for example could be to know all the dependencies I have in my queries, if for example I would store the full query in a column. Or if I have a list of distributed lists in an email and I want to know all the participants of a certain domain, for example.

Any ideas?

edited with the simple example.

Thanks to all that provided feedback. The question should be clear now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table(s); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and details of the expected output. Help us to help you by giving us an example of your problem; just talking around the problem without anything concrete to look at makes it very difficult to work out what the problem is and what you would expect as an answer.

Comment: Imagine you made a minimal reproducible example and we can help you solve that problem. Than perhaps we can in turn imagine a solution.

Comment: done with the example I didn't put it because I assumed it was clear enough but I think this is understandable now
@MT0

Comment: @Miguel is the example clear enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH matches ( text, match, idx, num_matches ) AS (
  SELECT text,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '(obj.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT(text, '(obj.*?)(,|$)')
  FROM   test_me
UNION ALL
  SELECT text,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '(obj.*?)(,|$)', 1, idx + 1, NULL, 1),
         idx + 1,
         num_matches
  FROM   matches
  WHERE  idx < num_matches
)
SELECT match
FROM   matches
WHERE  idx <= num_matches
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_me (
    text varchar(3000)
);

insert into test_me (text) VALUES (
'obj_a, obj_b,
trx_a, trx_c,
obj_c,
obj_d,
obj'
);
```

Outputs:

> | MATCH |
> | --- |
> | obj_a |
> | obj_b |
> | obj_c |
> | obj_d |
> | obj |

---

If you just want the output in a single row then:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '.*?(obj.*?(,|$)|$)', '\1', 1, 0, 'n') AS matches
FROM   test_me
```

Which outputs:

> | MATCHES |
> | --- |
> | obj_a,obj_b,obj_c,obj_d,obj |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ce95adfa06bc51da79d31839028b4ee)*

Comment: thanks for the feedback I tried to think of going at it using the regex_count but thought there was better way to do this but ok thanks for the feedback I guess this would work